# c++11 update pthread based code to std::thread or boost::thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I have the following code that I would like to update to be more portable and c++11 friendly.  However, I'm stuck as how to replace the pthread calls.  I can use std::this_thread::get_id() to get the thread id but can't tell if that thread is still alive.

```
  pthread_t activeThread = 0;

  pthread_t getCurrentThread() {
    return pthread_self();
  }

  bool isActiveThreadAlive() {
    if(activeThread == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return pthread_kill(activeThread, 0) != ESRCH;
  }
```

Potential std::thread version...

```
  std::thread::id activeThread = std::thread::id();

  std::thread::id getCurrentThread() {
    return std::this_thread::get_id();
  }

  bool isActiveThreadAlive() {
    if(activeThread == std::thread::id()) {
      return false;
    }
    return pthread_kill(activeThread, 0) != ESRCH;// <--- need replacement!!!
  }
```

What the code really needs to do is know if the thread has died from an exception or some other error that caused it to terminate without releasing the object.  As in the following...

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uLock = getLock();
while (activeThread != 0) {
  if (threadWait.wait_for(uLock, std::chrono::seconds(30)) == std::cv_status::timeout) {
    if (!isActiveThreadAlive()) {
      activeThread = 0;
    }
  }
}
activeThread = getCurrentThread();
uLock.unlock();
try {
  // do stuff here.
}
catch (const std::exception&) {
}
uLock.lock();
activeThread = 0;
```

And before anyone asks I do not have a guarantee of control over when, where or how the threads are created.  The threads that call the functions may be from anywhere.

Comment: `isActiveThreadAlive` is a confusingly named function. Perhaps `killActiveThreadIfAlive` would be a more descriptive name?

Comment: Checking the thread which you have no control of smells like introspection. As far as I know, C++ standard doesn't define *introspection* features. Knowing `thread::id` tells nothing about thread's current state. Note also, that POSIX specifies usage of `pthread_kill()` with ended thread as *Undefine Behavior*, so even original code is not standard-confirmant.

Comment: Jackie, isActiveThreadAlive does not kill the thread it send the signal value zero which does noting but the function still does the test if the thread is alive so the return value is still valid.  Essentially, it just tests to see if the thread is alive.

Comment: Tsyvarev, I'm not sure what introspection has to do with my code.  As I understand it Introspection is like reflection and has to do with accessing objects/functions that you don't know about at compile time.  I'm just trying to determine if the thread is alive or not.